# What visa type should I select when applying for a ancestry visa? (For the UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, working-visas, uk-citizenship, ancestry-visas

I am an Australian citizen and my Grandfather was born in the UK and am therefore eligible to apply for an ancestry visa. However when applying there does not seem to be an ancestry visa category.

[image]

When i select the work category, a that is what i intend to do the only options are...
[image]

What do I need to select when applying for an ancestry visa?

Comment: Did you look at all the categories?  An ancestry visa allows you to work, but it is not a work visa.

Comment: I thought the Ancestry Visa was a settlement visa.

Comment: @ouflak I'd have thought so too, but it did not appear to be listed in that category either.

Answer (score 4):

It's under Work -> Non Points Based Working Visas -> UK Ancestry