# Which visa type and subtype should I use when applying for a UK Ancestry dependent visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, dependent-visa, ancestry

I am a South African citizen. My wife can apply for a UK Ancestry visa and my child and I would like to apply as UK Ancestry dependents.

Please not that this is for a dependent visa application*, not a UK Ancestry visa as already covered here: [UK Ancestry Visa question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7426/what-visa-type-should-i-select-when-applying-for-a-ancestry-visa-for-the-uk)

I am trying to apply on www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk but I'm unable to find the correct visa type and subtype for dependents. There are a few options for dependent visas, but I can't be certain which is the correct one for myself and which is the correct one for my child (they may very well be different).

Unfortunately the "Contact Us" link on www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk isn't working and gov.uk aren't able to assist me.

Does someone know for certain which the correct option is for UK Ancestry dependent visa?

Comment: Based on the other Q&A that said to use work, non points-based working visas, possibly choose "dependants over 6 months" (there's a "dependants up to 6 months" option too). I couldn't find anything else that looked appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. That is the one I was considering for myself, however, any type of working visa isn't really applicable for my 3 year old daughter. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original OP contacted the paid-for [UK Visa and Immigration team](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk) and asked them the same question.

Their reply is as follows:

> [OP and his daughter] can apply as dependants on [OP's wife's] ancestry visa.
>
> When you make visa application on www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk website, when it comes to chose options to select visa, you need to fill details as follows :
>
> Reason for visit : Work
>   Visa type : Non points based working visas
>   Visa sub-type : Dependant more than 6 months.
>
> We would also like to inform you that you need to make 2 separate visa applications, one for each [dependent].