# UK Ancestry Visa - which application type for dependents (wife)

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, dependent-visa, ancestry-visas, ancestry

I'm struggling to understand which application form to select for the dependent of a UK Ancestry Visa applicant? I am the UK Ancestry Visa applicant and am applying with my wife as a dependent at the same time.

I am confident I meet the requirements for the UK Ancestry Visa and that my wife can come with me, I'm just not sure which application type to choose.

For myself I have chosen:

- Reason for visit: Work
- Visa type: Non Point based working visa
- Visa sub-type: UK Ancestry

Would my wife be the same?

Or would she be:

- Reason for Visit: Work
- Visa type: Non Points-Based Visas
- Visa subtype: Dependants 6 months or more

This last approach seem more right to me (and it is the answer found on this question [Which visa type and subtype should I use when applying for a UK Ancestry dependent visa?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/11533/which-visa-type-and-subtype-should-i-use-when-applying-for-a-uk-ancestry-depende)) However, if you take this route, in the application it asks for the 'UK Sponsor'. My wife won't have a 'sponsor' in the sense of an employer as this is not a requirement for ancestry visa dependents. So I wonder if this is not the right approach.

I can't find any information online that addresses this question.

I have asked via the official channels by paying to email them. However the answers haven't been clear so I'm still a bit uncertain.

Does anyone know?

Comment: Could you post the (redacted) replies you received.  We might be able to interpret them.